# Nginx proxy_pass to remote file

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have an nginx server where I'd like to point any route that begins with `/app` to a specific file. It's a single page app, so even `/app/some/long/route` should just return the same index.html file.

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass http://my-cdn-host.com/index.html;
}
```

I'm having 2 problems:

1. I'm pretty sure that `/app/very/long/url` does a proxy_pass to `http://my-cdn-host.com/index.html/app/very/long/url` which is not wanted
2. It's not clear to me based on the logs exactly what the proxied URL is, so I can't even fully confirm the point above. `$proxy_host` and `$upstream_addr` don't have that full information

One final note: even though the file is `http://my-cdn-host.com/index.html`, I'm unable to access it with just `http://my-cdn-host.com/`. The `index.html` needs to be the explicit path.

Is there a way I can serve a single remote file for my location? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the expected behavior, described in the `proxy_pass` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If the `proxy_pass` directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
> }
> ```

You need to use another `proxy_pass` behavior feature, described somewhat below:

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> ...
>
> - When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the `rewrite` directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (`break`):
>
>   ```
>   location /name/ {
>       rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
>   }
>   ```
>
>   In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

Use the following location block:

```
location /app {
    rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    proxy_pass http://my-cdn-host.com;
}
```